# How does explicit type conversion to a contract work?

Tags: solidity

Following is an example from the [Solidity doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/contracts.html#creating-contracts), but I have three questions:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.7.0;

contract OwnedToken {
    TokenCreator creator;
    address owner;
    bytes32 name;

    constructor(bytes32 _name) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender); // this part
        name = _name;
    }

    function changeName(bytes32 newName) public {
        if (msg.sender == address(creator)) {
            name = newName;
        }
    }

    function transfer(address newOwner) public {
        if (msg.sender != owner) return;

        if (creator.isTokenTransferOK(owner, newOwner))
            owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract TokenCreator {
    function createToken(bytes32 name) public returns (OwnedToken tokenAddress) {
        return new OwnedToken(name);
    }

    function changeName(OwnedToken tokenAddress, bytes32 name) public {
        tokenAddress.changeName(name);
    }

    function isTokenTransferOK(address currentOwner, address newOwner) public pure returns (bool ok) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(currentOwner, newOwner))[0] == 0x7f;
    }
}
```

1. I'm trying to understand how this conversion works:

```
creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender);
```

I get the concept that what it's doing is an explicit type conversion, just like you'd do with `uint(something)`, but I'm not sure the exact mechanism behind it.  I don't see a constructor in the contract `TokenCreater` or a function that allows this conversion.  Also, can you only convert an address to the contract type of this kind, like how this example converted `msg.sender` to the `TokenCreater` type, or can you pass other types like `uint` or an array?

2. The document explains that

> It is fine for the contract `OwnedToken` to reference `TokenCreator`
>   as long as it is not used to create a new contract.

Why is that so?

3. `OwnedToken` references `TokenCreator`:

```
TokenCreator creator;
creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender);
if (creator.isTokenTransferOK(owner, newOwner))
   owner = newOwner;
```

But, `TokenCreator` references `OwnedToken` as well:

```
    function createToken(bytes32 name) public returns (OwnedToken tokenAddress) {
        return new OwnedToken(name);
    }
```

This recursive referencing is a bit confusing. Is this common and a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that this answers your question:

```
// Set `creator1` to point to a `TokenCreator` contract deployed at address `msg.sender`:
TokenCreator creator1 = TokenCreator(msg.sender);

// Construct (deploy) a new `TokenCreator` contract, and set `creator2` to point to it:
TokenCreator creator2 = new TokenCreator("name");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't `TokenCreator` a contract account with an address of its own (derived from the sender) and `msg.sender` an external account with another address of its own? When you say "a `TokenCreator` contract deployed at address `msg.sender`", do you mean the contract account's address?

Comment: Also, the documentation shows `creator1 = TokenCreator(msg.sender)` as a type conversion process from `address` to `TokenCreator` as opposed to your explanation that this is a process of pointing at an `address`.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @Kevvv: It's the same thing. I've actually borrowed the *pointer* terminology from native languages (C/C++). It's probably not used that much in this Context (Solidity), but the meaning is the same. `TokenCreator(msg.sender)` is just a casting from `address` type to `TokenCreator` type. Both types are of the same length (160 bits), and in fact - in the ABI, they are both translated into `address`.

Comment: @Kevvv: Regarding your first comment (which I just saw) - "Isn't `TokenCreator` a contract account with an address of its own" - you can deploy many instances of `TokenCreator`, each one with its own unique address.